# HTML - Show/Hide Buttons on Bootstrap Panel collapse/expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap collapsible panel.
Here's the [Fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/71jd0mof/) for it

I'm trying to do the following :

1. I want to move both the buttons on the Panel header(at the extreme
   right end) i.e. exactly opposite to the text "Panel"
2. But I only want the buttons to be visible when the panel is expanded. And
   when the panel is hidden the buttons should be hidden too.

How can I achieve this. What would be the JS for it?

I tried to do the following in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
        $("#btnSearch").hide();
         $(".panel-title").click(function () {         
             $("#btnSearch").show();            
      });
});
```

But with this the buttons won't hide when the panel is made to hide.

Comment: add  your complete code

Comment: both button at the same horizontal levels as "panel" ?

Comment: Well most of you have almost given correct solution to achieve my requirement. But there's one problem though : Clicking the button causes the panel to hide. This should not be the case. Is there any way to prevent the panel from hiding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this. I moved your buttons to panel-heading itself and positioned them using `position:absolute;`.

It is very similar to this [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/970Wx)

```js
$(".panel-success").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('.buttonCon').addClass('vis');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('.buttonCon').removeClass('vis');
})
```

```css
.panel{
  position:relative;
}
.buttonCon{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:10px;
  display:none;
}
.buttonCon.vis{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="buttonCon">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ReloadData()">
            Button1
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" onclick="ReloadData()"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" id="clearAll" data-toggle="tooltip" title="btn2">
            Buttonn2
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
    <div class="panel-heading panelHeader" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#body" style="cursor:pointer;">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-expand"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Panel
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body collapse" id="body">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Label1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-form-label">Label 1</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="form-control roundedElement" type="text" id="txt1" />
        </div>

        <label for="Label2" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label alignment">Label 2</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="form-control roundedElement" type="text" id="txt2" />
        </div>

        <label for="Label3" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label alignment">Label 3</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="form-control roundedElement" type="text" id="txt3" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
          
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you double click on the panel there is a possibility for the buttons to appear when the panel is collapsed or disappear when the panel is shown. This is kind of a race condition and potentially this answer will cause more problems in the long run.

Comment: thank you BuddhistBeast for your important feedback. I updated my answer

Comment: It works well. But there's one problem though : Clicking these buttons causes the panel to hide. This should not be the case. Is there any way to prevent the panel from hiding?

Comment: ok. I updated the answer. you can check it now. If it solves the problem. can you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bootstrap collapse events to achieve it.

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".buttons").show();
})
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(".buttons").hide();
})
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muhsin84/71jd0mof/3/).

Answer (score 3):

The following [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71jd0mof/2/) is another option compared to the answers already given.

Mainly, it prevents the use of `position: absolute` which can result in a mish-mash of bad things happening. The following jQuery (which is readily available since you are using bootstrap) will work:

```
$("#js-panel").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('.js-toggle-btn').removeClass('hide');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('.js-toggle-btn').addClass('hide');
})
```

Take note that there are events to track whether a panel is currently opening or closing (plus two others), which can be found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events).

I would also suggest that you take the time to read some of the documentation/examples found on the bootstrap webpage, only because a lot of your css/html is pretty rough/unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by combining the answers provided by **@kittyCat** (the updated solution) and **@BuddhistBeast** .

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6m1d12mh/).

HTML code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-success" id="js-panel">

    <div class="panelButtons">
      <button type="reset" class="js-toggle-btn btn-warning pull-right btn-xs hide" id="clearAll" data-toggle="tooltip" title="btn2" style="margin-left:5px;">
        Button2
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="js-toggle-btn btn btn-primary pull-right btn-xs hide" onclick="ReloadData()">
        Button1
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-heading panelHeader" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#body" style="cursor:pointer;">
      <div class="panel-title">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-expand"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Panel
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body collapse" id="body">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Label1" class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-form-label">Label 1</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="form-control roundedElement" type="text" id="txt1" />
        </div>

        <label for="Label2" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label alignment">Label 2</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="form-control roundedElement" type="text" id="txt2" />
        </div>

        <label for="Label3" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label alignment">Label 3</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="form-control roundedElement" type="text" id="txt3" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS Code :

```
$("#js-panel").on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('.js-toggle-btn').removeClass('hide');
}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('.js-toggle-btn').addClass('hide');
})
```

Comment: Wanted to accept  both of your answers but I can only select any of the one. Hence I have accepted the updated solution provided by @kittyCat  as it solves the problem of panel being hidden on button click